# Does File.mkdirs() need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: java, android, file

Does below code need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission? I mean does  file.mkdirs(); need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to write file

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    filename = sdf.format(new Date());

    try {
        String path = ctx.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "thinkly");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File file2 = new File(file, filename + ".jpg");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file2);

        capturedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        return file2.getAbsolutePath();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: No. `getFilesDir()` is your app's internal storage. Also, you don't need the `getApplicationContext()` call there. You can just call `getFilesDir()` on any `Context`. It will always return the same thing. And you don't need to handle the path as a `String` ever. You can just do `File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "thinkly");`.

Comment: `File.mkdirs()` doesn't write a file, it creates directories. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Android devices have two file storage options: internal storage and external storage.

**internal storage:**

- Files saved here are accessible by only your app.
- When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's
  files from internal storage.

**External storage:**

- It's world-readable, so files saved here may be read outside of your
  control.
- When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes your app's
  files from here only if you save them in the directory from
  getExternalFilesDir().

**These are the common file access functions in Android, so you can know what needs permission and what doesn't:**

- getFilesDir() - No permission is required
- getCacheDir() - No permission is required
- getExternalFilesDirs() - Permission is required
- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() - Permission is required

**In conclusion**

In your code, you use the getFilesDir() method - so you do not need to ask for permission.

extrad:

**External storage permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```